# Unclosed div when wrapping every 2 divs in a loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following set up below.  I'm trying to wrap ever 2 divs in a "row".

When its an even number it works great, but when there's an odd number, I end with an open div and get html errors.  Any ideas on how to better make sure there is a closing div would be appreciated

```
<?php

            $args = array(            
              'post_type' => 'portfolio-project',
              'posts_per_page' => -1, 
              'orderby' => 'menu_order',
              'order' => 'ASC'
            );

            $query = query_posts($args);

        ?>

        <?php $i=1; ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if($i==1 || $i%2==1) echo '<div class="row">' ;?>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php the_title();?>
            </div>

            <?php if($i%2==0) echo '</div>' ; ?>

        <?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: you are checking one condition to open div different condition to close div then how it will properly close

Comment: <?php if($i%2==0) echo '</div>' ; ?> repeat this line after endwhile; I think it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @ManishShukla You should post as answer, the other answers below are neither clear nor clean coding compared to yours.

Comment: @ManishShukla See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php $i++; endwhile; if($i%2==1) echo '</div>' ; wp_reset_query();?>
```

in place of

```
<?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: This would be correct, but you need to change it back to checking $i%2==0, like your original comment had (this is because there is an $i++ that happens at the end of the while loop right after that condition failed, but will now pass). Right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put and end close tag if needed. I change the counting method to be more clear.

```
    <?php $i=1;  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if($i==1) echo '<div class="row">' ;?>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php the_title();?>
        </div>

        <?php if($i==2) echo '</div>' ; ?>

    <?php $i++; if($i>2)$i=1;endwhile; wp_reset_query();if($i==2) echo '</div>' ;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
<?php $i = 2; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($i == 2 || $i % 2 == 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($i == 2 || $i % 2 == 0) echo '</div>'; ?>

    <?php $i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the count of number of div's that are open

Change this

```
<?php if($i==1 || $i%2==1) echo '<div class="row">';?>
```

to

```
<?php if($i==1 || $i%2==1){ echo '<div class="row">'; $count = 1;} ?>
```

And Check if count==1 while closing the div

```
<?php if($count==1){ echo '</div>' ; $count=0; } ?>
```